# Translate Handbrake preset into FFMPEG preset

Tags: ffmpeg, handbrake

Is there a good way to translate the following Handbrake preset code into a FFMPEG preset? I've not found any reliable sources for how to configure the preset for FFMPEG.

`{ "PresetList": [ { "AlignAVStart": true, "AudioCopyMask": [ "copy:aac", "copy:ac3", "copy:dtshd", "copy:dts", "copy:mp3", "copy:truehd", "copy:flac", "copy:eac3" ], "AudioEncoderFallback": "ac3", "AudioLanguageList": [ "any" ], "AudioList": [ { "AudioBitrate": 160, "AudioCompressionLevel": 0.0, "AudioEncoder": "copy", "AudioMixdown": "none", "AudioNormalizeMixLevel": false, "AudioSamplerate": "auto", "AudioTrackQualityEnable": false, "AudioTrackQuality": -1.0, "AudioTrackGainSlider": 0.0, "AudioTrackDRCSlider": 0.0 } ], "AudioSecondaryEncoderMode": true, "AudioTrackSelectionBehavior": "all", "ChapterMarkers": true, "ChildrenArray": [], "Default": false, "FileFormat": "av_mp4", "Folder": false, "FolderOpen": false, "Mp4HttpOptimize": true, "Mp4iPodCompatible": false, "PictureAutoCrop": true, "PictureBottomCrop": 278, "PictureLeftCrop": 0, "PictureRightCrop": 0, "PictureTopCrop": 278, "PictureDARWidth": 3840, "PictureDeblockPreset": "off", "PictureDeblockTune": "medium", "PictureDeblockCustom": "strength=strong:thresh=20:blocksize=8", "PictureDeinterlaceFilter": "decomb", "PictureCombDetectPreset": "default", "PictureCombDetectCustom": "", "PictureDeinterlacePreset": "default", "PictureDeinterlaceCustom": "", "PictureDenoiseCustom": "", "PictureDenoiseFilter": "off", "PictureDenoisePreset": "light", "PictureDenoiseTune": "none", "PictureSharpenCustom": "", "PictureSharpenFilter": "off", "PictureSharpenPreset": "medium", "PictureSharpenTune": "none", "PictureDetelecine": "off", "PictureDetelecineCustom": "", "PictureItuPAR": false, "PictureKeepRatio": true, "PictureLooseCrop": false, "PictureModulus": 2, "PicturePAR": "auto", "PicturePARWidth": 1, "PicturePARHeight": 1, "PictureForceHeight": 0, "PictureForceWidth": 0, "PresetName": "PS4 English (GPU)", "Type": 1, "UsesPictureFilters": true, "UsesPictureSettings": 2, "SubtitleAddCC": false, "SubtitleAddForeignAudioSearch": false, "SubtitleAddForeignAudioSubtitle": false, "SubtitleBurnBehavior": "none", "SubtitleBurnBDSub": false, "SubtitleBurnDVDSub": false, "SubtitleLanguageList": [ "und", "eng" ], "SubtitleTrackSelectionBehavior": "none", "VideoAvgBitrate": 0, "VideoColorMatrixCode": 0, "VideoEncoder": "nvenc_h265", "VideoFramerateMode": "vfr", "VideoGrayScale": false, "VideoScaler": "swscale", "VideoPreset": "medium", "VideoTune": "", "VideoProfile": "auto", "VideoLevel": "4.1", "VideoOptionExtra": "", "VideoQualityType": 2, "VideoQualitySlider": 30.0, "VideoQSVDecode": false, "VideoQSVAsyncDepth": 4, "VideoTwoPass": false, "VideoTurboTwoPass": false, "x264UseAdvancedOptions": false }, { "AlignAVStart": false, "AudioCopyMask": [ "copy:aac", "copy:ac3", "copy:dtshd", "copy:dts", "copy:mp3", "copy:truehd", "copy:flac", "copy:eac3" ], "AudioEncoderFallback": "ac3", "AudioLanguageList": [ "any" ], "AudioList": [ { "AudioBitrate": 160, "AudioCompressionLevel": 0.0, "AudioEncoder": "copy", "AudioMixdown": "none", "AudioNormalizeMixLevel": false, "AudioSamplerate": "auto", "AudioTrackQualityEnable": false, "AudioTrackQuality": -1.0, "AudioTrackGainSlider": 0.0, "AudioTrackDRCSlider": 0.0 } ], "AudioSecondaryEncoderMode": true, "AudioTrackSelectionBehavior": "all", "ChapterMarkers": true, "ChildrenArray": [], "Default": false, "FileFormat": "av_mkv", "Folder": false, "FolderOpen": false, "Mp4HttpOptimize": false, "Mp4iPodCompatible": false, "PictureAutoCrop": true, "PictureBottomCrop": 278, "PictureLeftCrop": 0, "PictureRightCrop": 0, "PictureTopCrop": 278, "PictureDARWidth": 3840, "PictureDeblockPreset": "off", "PictureDeblockTune": "medium", "PictureDeblockCustom": "strength=strong:thresh=20:blocksize=8", "PictureDeinterlaceFilter": "decomb", "PictureCombDetectPreset": "default", "PictureCombDetectCustom": "", "PictureDeinterlacePreset": "default", "PictureDeinterlaceCustom": "", "PictureDenoiseCustom": "", "PictureDenoiseFilter": "off", "PictureDenoisePreset": "light", "PictureDenoiseTune": "none", "PictureSharpenCustom": "", "PictureSharpenFilter": "off", "PictureSharpenPreset": "medium", "PictureSharpenTune": "none", "PictureDetelecine": "off", "PictureDetelecineCustom": "", "PictureItuPAR": false, "PictureKeepRatio": true, "PictureLooseCrop": false, "PictureModulus": 2, "PicturePAR": "auto", "PicturePARWidth": 1, "PicturePARHeight": 1, "PictureForceHeight": 0, "PictureForceWidth": 0, "PresetName": "Movies", "Type": 1, "UsesPictureFilters": true, "UsesPictureSettings": 2, "SubtitleAddCC": false, "SubtitleAddForeignAudioSearch": false, "SubtitleAddForeignAudioSubtitle": false, "SubtitleBurnBehavior": "none", "SubtitleBurnBDSub": false, "SubtitleBurnDVDSub": false, "SubtitleLanguageList": [ "any" ], "SubtitleTrackSelectionBehavior": "all", "VideoAvgBitrate": 0, "VideoColorMatrixCode": 0, "VideoEncoder": "nvenc_h265", "VideoFramerateMode": "vfr", "VideoGrayScale": false, "VideoScaler": "swscale", "VideoPreset": "medium", "VideoTune": "", "VideoProfile": "auto", "VideoLevel": "4.0", "VideoOptionExtra": "", "VideoQualityType": 2, "VideoQualitySlider": 30.0, "VideoQSVDecode": false, "VideoQSVAsyncDepth": 4, "VideoTwoPass": false, "VideoTurboTwoPass": false, "x264UseAdvancedOptions": false } ], "VersionMajor": 42, "VersionMicro": 0, "VersionMinor": 0 }`

Comment: Handbrake already uses ffmpeg under the hood. Why do you want to switch?

Comment: Unsure this question can be reasonably answered in a generalized way, but Handbrake at least refuses va-api support as "inferior" to proprietary closed-source driver APIs. If it'll be a cold day in hell before you run one (e.g. because you've done so in the past), closed source video drivers might be a non-starter, and ffmpeg apparently has more/better support.